# Correlation matrix plot - plt.colorbar() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation

I created a function that creates a correlation matrix:

```
 def correlation_matrix(df):
         f = plt.figure(figsize=(19, 15))
         plt.matshow(df.corr(), fignum=f.number)
         plt.xticks(range(df.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), 
                    df.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14, rotation=45)
         plt.yticks(range(df.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), 
         df.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14)
         cb = plt.colorbar()
         cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
         plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=18);
```

The function seems to work, as I do get a correlation matrix plot when I execute `correlation_matrix(my_df)`. Yet, the plot is black and grey and the matrix does not contain any colour, while the plt.colorbar() should provide coloring. [image]

Comment: Are you looking for a `cmap`?

Comment: `plt.matshow(data, cmap="RdYlBu")`?  By default, the colormap is `viridis` (with purple, greenish and yellowish colors), so the defaults at your system seem to be altered. See also [matplotlib's colormap tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

Comment: Ah thx both! The cmap addition did work. I was fine with the default but somehow it only gave a black/white theme as output.